# Mann schlägt Frau mit Kopftuch - Bindungsunklarheit?

Tags: single-word-request

In the above headline from *[Welt Online](https://www.welt.de/politik/deutschland/article176226347/Berlin-Frau-mit-Kopftuch-angegriffen-Saleh-sieht-mehr-Islamfeindlichkeit.html)* most would interpret the sentence as meaning *the woman was wearing a headscarf*, not that *the man hit her with a headscarf*. In other words, the prepositional phrase attaches to the woman, not the man.

Conversely, most will interpret:

- Mann schlägt Frau mit Fleischklopfer - [Source](https://www.augsburger-allgemeine.de/donauwoerth/Mann-schlaegt-Frau-mit-Fleischklopfer-id42485176.html)

as meaning *the man used a meat mallet to hit the woman*.  Here the prepositional phrase attaches to the man, not the woman.

This linguistic feature is called *attachment ambiguity* in English. For example, see [this article](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=17711) on *Language Log*.

So, finally, to my question. *Google Translate* gives *Bindungsunklarheit* as the German equivalent, but a search on the word results in only two, irrelevant hits. What is the German term for this linguistic phenomenon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general linguistic German term should be

> [Ambiguität](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ambiguit%C3%A4t) (Mehrdeutigkeit von Wörtern oder Sätzen)

and in your special case: Skopusambiguität (Bereichsmehrdeutigkeit)

Here are some [examples](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mehrdeutigkeit#Bereichsmehrdeutigkeit:_doppeldeutige_Bez%C3%BCge).

Comment: More specifically: "strukturelle Ambiguität", since the ambiguity is in the sentence's structure rather than in the meaning of a single word.